# Cross-platform C GUI

Tags: open-source, library, cross-platform, gui, c

My friend and I are developing a C software, he's developing it on Windows, I'm contributing and I use Xubuntu. As far as I know, Qt supports C++ and not C, and as far as I know GTK sucks on Windows, and I heard horror stories of people developing GTK software on Windows. I'm looking for:

- A cross-platform C GUI (Windows, Linux and Mac, 32 bit and  64 bit)
- Free and open source, I do not want to worry about licensing
- Maintained
- Modern looking
- Lightweight
- Easy to learn, I want to learn it quickly
- Well documented, and has sample applications (examples)
- Support team or forums with active members or active IRC channel
- Big bonus if I don't have to download an SDK in order to use a GUI library, all I want is to create some windows with few buttons.

Comment: 1. If you know C, what is wrong with C++? 2. You probably won't find something better than Qt with the features you are looking for.

Comment: @Cornelius i know c++ too, it's just my partner in the project, he's a retired programmer, spent years doing C and would like to use the language he knows best, he doesn't know C++ and would like to do it in C if possible

Comment: If he knows C then he already knows a lot about C++. Here are the main differences http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html

Comment: @Cornelius I sent him the link lets  see if that's enough to convince him, but still the  question stands, it will be nice if there's such gui

Comment: Also send him this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#High-level_widget_toolkits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can accept HTML5/JS as GUI then take a look at the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF):

https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

The base CEF framework includes support for the C and C++ programming languages.

CEF supports javascript bindings and callbacks, so you can communicate asynchronously both ways between C <> JS.

Here is an example on how to use CEF C API (a github project of mine):
https://github.com/CzarekTomczak/cefcapi

Comment: Spotify uses this for example

Answer (score 11):

It is worth taking a look at [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org) - it is a cross platform GUI library written in C++ but it can be used from C and also has bindings for python, ruby, perl and others.

- Cross Platform - Yes Windows/Linux/OS-X/Others - 64 & 32 bit.
- Free & Open Source - Yes and with a permissive, (LGPL compatible), licence.
- Maintained - Actively developed and maintained as it has been since 1992.
- Modern Looking - Actually wxWidgets looks native on most platforms because where possibly it acts as a wrapper arround the native widgets so on XP it looks XP on Win 7 it looks Win 7, etc.
- Lightweight - Very for the reason above.
- Easy to learn - Lots of documentation, examples, demos and online resources.
- Well documented and examples - see the line above.
- Support team - Very active forums and mailing list, *including the main authors.*
- Don't need and SDK - Yes you use your existing development tool chain to build from source or you can download binary distributions for:

  - Windows as wxMSW DLLs for the selected compilers:

    - Visual C++ 2008-2013
    - TDM-GCC 4.7 and 4.8
  - Ubuntu / Debian Packages
  - Fedora / openSUSE Packages

Comment: _I know that another answer has already been accepted for this but still feel it is worth a mention._

Answer (score 0):

Also :

- [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)
- [gtk](https://www.gtk.org)
- Glut
- [IUP = Portable User Interface](https://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)
- [SFML = Simple and Fast Multimedia Library](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)
- [Nuklear](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear) - A single-header ANSI C immediate mode cross-platform GUI library

Comment: This is just a list of links, can you detail what they are, main features and the like? Is there any one you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can try NAppGUI. [www.nappgui.com](http://www.nappgui.com)

Uses ANSI C, its open source and connect with core technologies in each platform (Win32, Cocoa, GTK3)